# how to select multipe user for one Campaign and the skip the user which is already present in that campaign?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to select multiple users for one compaign and if the user is already selected that user - skip it.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(AssignCampainToUserViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await this._employeeService.AssignCampaignToUserAsync(model);
         if (result)
         {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
         }
      
        return View("Error");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

From controllor it will come to `AssignCampaignToUserAsync` method here it wil get the user and comapaign id and it will assign the user to compaign

```
public async Task<bool> AssignCampaignToUserAsync(AssignCampainToUserViewModel model)
{
    var checkUserHasCapain = await this._UserRepositery
        .CheckUserAssignCompaignAsync(model.UserId, model.CampaignId)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (checkUserHasCapain != null) 
    {
        var userCampaign =  new AssigningCampainCustomModel()
        {
            UserId = checkUserHasCapain,
            CampaignId = model.CampaignId,
        };
        
        await this._UserRepositery
            .AssignCampaigToUserAsync(userCampaign)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
            
        await this._UserRepositery
            .Save()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        return true;
      }
      
      return false;
    }
}
```

Here it will check user is valid or not and campaign is valid or not and the user is available in user campaign table or not and it will give the unassign user

```
public async Task <IList<int>> CheckUserAssignCompaignAsync(IList<int> UserId, int CampaignId)
{
    var campainByUserId = from users in this._userMasterContext.User
                          where UserId.Contains(users.UserId) && users.IsActive 
                          &&!users.IsDeleted join campaign in this._userMasterContext.
                          Campaign on CampaignId equals campaign.CampaignId 
                          where campaign.IsActive == true && !campaign.IsDeleted 
                          && !(from userCampaign in this._userMasterContext.
                          UserCampaign userCampaign.CampaignId == CampaignId 
                          select userCampaign.UserId).ToList().Contains(users.UserId) 
                          select users.UserId;
                          
    return await campainByUserId.ToListAsync();
}
```

It will create the user:

```
public async Task AssignCampaigToUserAsync(AssigningCampainCustomModel model)
{
    if(model.UserId !=null)
    {
        foreach (var user in model.UserId)
        {
            UserCampaign userCampaign = new UserCampaign()
            {
                UserId = user,
                CampaignId = model.CampaignId,
            };
            
            await this._userMasterContext
                .UserCampaign
                .AddRangeAsync(userCampaign);
        }
    }    
}
```

While assigning users to campaign I want to select multiple users  for one campaign.

Comment: What's  the issue you are facing? I think if you want to have `campaignA-UserA, campaignA-UserB` then you only need to insert multi rows, if you want to have `campaignA - UserA,UserB,UserC`, then you need to set the table to have a users column then only insert one record for a campaign..

Comment: i want to inser multiple user for one campaign means multiselect

Comment: yes, then how you design you data table , and do you have any issue?

Comment: [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Id required")]
        public IList<int> UserId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campaign Id required")]
        public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    }

Comment: not getting userid after selecting Showing null